# IntelliJ - is it possible to add custom annotation e.g. @SecurityCheck to all methods of a controller classes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created an annotation e.g. @SecurityCheck and a (Restfull) controller advice to check if the controller has @SecurityCheck annotation.

I have almost 300 controller methods. Its very difficult for me to apply @SecurityCheck on each and every method in all controller ***by hand***.

Is there a way by which I can add a particular code snippit e.g @SecurityCheck on every method of controller layer in my project. I am using InteliJ.

Example:

Here is a code snippet for a sample controller method. And every controller method has @ApiResponses() annotation.

```
/... some other annotations .../
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = Response.class) })
public Response getExampleResourceMethod(
        @RequestBody String id) {
    return someService.getData(id);
}
```

Method name can be different and Arguments. But almost All Methods has @ApiResponses() annotation with different annotation params.

Expected Output

```
/... some other annotations .../
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = Response.class) })
@SecurityCheck()
public Response getExampleResourceMethod(
        @RequestBody String id) {
    return someService.getData(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it with a Regex and the search & replace tool

EDIT: 
Quick example of a solution below:

Search: `(@ApiResponses\((\S[\n]?.*)}\))`

Replace: `$1\r\n@SecurityCheck`

Comment: What could be the regex ? All controller methods has different names, different annotations. Replace will work on searched term. I dont think it will work

Comment: I think it's better to declare the `SecurityCheck` once instead of adding it everywhere (less duplication) but I added a quick example above to do it via a regex, I don't keep the style with it but that can give you a guess of how to do it :)

Comment: It looks like duplication but in future this annotation will be updated with appropriate permissions.

Comment: Ok, My ALL controller methods has this annotation. @ApiResponses({
   @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = List.class) }) .  @ApiResponses( part is constant , remaining is dynamic. Can you help me to make Regex for this which search this in whole project and add @SceurityCheck on next line .

Comment: can you please update your original post with an example? Will be easier for me to help you

Comment: Use [Structural search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) Check these examples: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#e470d987

Comment: Regex updated, I did not know about the Structural search and Replace but it looks like a very good one

Comment: For Now Your updated Regex with some modifications Worked. Thanks Alot. I will also go through Structural Search.